# OSX Lion recovery

Tags: macos, partitioning, osx-lion, partition-recovery

I really screwed the pooch last night and in preparation to sell my Macbook Air, I used GParted to blow out my partitions (I was running a Boot Camp Windows 7). Well, I must have been tired because I blew out the restore partition as well. What are my options to get at least the recovery partition back on the computer? It has not been quite one year since I purchased the laptop, am I possibly still covered by the warranty? Has anyone run into this same issue or know someone who has?

Please go gently on me, I've already beat myself up enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a way to install just the recovery partition that don't involve either cloning it from another Mac that already has one, or reinstalling Lion (the installer will automatically recreate it).  You're probably going to have to reinstall Lion:

1. If your Mac has new enough firmware, you can use [Lion Internet Recovery](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718).  Start the Mac holding <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>, and it'll boot from a recovery partition on Apple's servers.  From that, you can reinstall Lion (and it'll automatically recreate the recovery partition).
2. If you have a Snow Leopard install disc, you can reinstall that, update to 10.6.8, download the Lion installer from the App Store, and reinstall Lion that way.
3. Finally, you can buy a [Lion installer (USB drive)](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD256Z/A?) and install from that.

Comment: Option 1 worked surprisingly enough. I thought that was the partition I blew out. In any case, I don't need to understand it, I only need to accept it.I cannot thank you (nor this site) enough. The next beer is on me.

Comment: You probably did blow it away; the internet version of Lion Recovery works even if the recovery partition isn't there.  BTW, since this worked for you, please [accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).